# List of parts to buy for to "upgrade" existing Mindstorms NXT 1.0 to Mindstorms EV3 set?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, nxt

Is there a list of parts available I need to buy to "upgrade" an existing Mindstorms NXT 1.0 (8527) set to a Mindstorms EV3 set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of such a list, but you can find the inventory for the EV3 on [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=31313-1) and other similar sites.

However, it would be more economical to buy an entire EV3 set. The 31313 retail set is about $350 (USD). To buy just the EV3 brick, motors and sensors individually would be more than that.

- EV3 Intelligent Brick - $190
- EV3 Large Motor - $25 x 2
- EV3 Medium Motor - $20
- EV3 Infrared Sensor - $30
- EV3 Infrared Beacon - $30
- EV3 Touch Sensor - $20
- EV3 Color Sensor - $40
- **Total: $380**

---

It is also possible to use the EV3 programming software (the desktop version) to program the NXT brick (with some limitations, like no Bluetooth support). So, you could "upgrade" the software without having to obtain any new parts.